# How can I make my own mesh and add it to Addmenu > Mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, add-on

As Blender is an open-source Program of coarse I can **Edit** its program files !

I want to make my own mesh (Car/Bus/) and I want it become a a regular mesh In add menu like a cube,sphere (Because I use it many times)

### Why?

I do not want my mesh to be in file and every time i want to use i must imported.

How Can i Make it ? - Of coarse it will be made with Python - ( Are n't I right ? )

N.B :
Plese in answer Be ware that i am new to blender python. bpy.

### Refrence

Consider that this is my mesh:
[image]

And I Want Its Shortcut in This Menu Here:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to create your own add-on for this. First create a Python function that [creates the mesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html), then create an operator to call that Python function, then add the operator to a menu. There are loads of online tutorials on how to do these things; the [Blender API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/) is a good start, as it also includes information about best practices and common pitfalls.

You can check out the built-in [Add Extra Objects](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Extra) add-on to look at similar functionality.